# I am getting Error: 13 INTERNAL: No message received when replacing grpc with @grpc/grpc-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, grpc-node

When i am trying to switch to new grpc package (@grpc/grpc-js)from existing package(grpc) in my existing code i am getting the error

**code**

```
const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");
const confiq = require('confiq').default;

const PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/proto';
const { url, port } = confiq('style')

const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    `${PROTO_PATH}/style.proto`,
    {
        longs: Number,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true,
        includeDirs: 
        [
          PROTO_PATH
        ]
    });

const SERVICE_URL = `${url}:${port}`
const StyleProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).com.xxx.style;
const grpcCredentials = grpc.credentials.createInsecure();

function call(method, requestData) {
  const clientStub = new StyleProto.StyleService(SERVICE_URL, grpcCredentials, { 
    'grpc.max_send_message_length': 10485760,
    'grpc.max_receive_message_length': 629145600
 });
  if (!clientStub[method])
      throw new Error('Method not available');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      clientStub[method](requestData, (err, data) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data)
          if (err || data.statusResponse.statusType === 'ERROR')
              reject(err || data);
          resolve(data);
      });
  });
}

module.exports = call;
```

**ERROR**

```
 at callErrorFromStatus (xxx/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (xxx/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:180:80)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (xxx/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (xxx/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at xxx/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest xxx/style-service-client/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> xxx/style-service-client/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> xxx/style-service-client/src/adsTest.js:29:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 13,
  details: 'No message received',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}
```

If i change back the first line back to
const grpc = require('grpc')
it starts working again

As much as i know the packages are supposed to be compatible with each other, not sure if i am missing anything here

**Package version**

```
"@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.8.18",
"@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.8",
"async": "^3.2.4",
"confiq": "0.0.3",
"grpc": "^1.24.11",
"lodash": "^4.17.21"
```

Node version v14.20.1

Comment: That error indicates that the client made a unary request and received an OK status without receiving a response message, which is invalid. You say that it "starts working again" with the old grpc package; do you actually receive a message when you use that library?

Comment: yes @murgatroid99 I receive message when i change to 'grpc' library